# getting error unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Tags: python, ironpython

I have windows form app where-in I'm passing `DataTable` from C# to `IronPython`.

But when running the python script, it gives error

> unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'.

I searched a lot but could not find what is wrong in my script.

--------   C# code --------

```
DataTable mytable = new DataTable();
mytable = MainTable.Copy();

// Column "TimeStamp" is of typeof(int)

var engine = Python.CreateEngine();
ScriptScope scope = engine.CreateScope();
scope.SetVariable("mytable", mytable);
ScriptSource ss = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromString(
    txtPythonCode.Text.Trim(), SourceCodeKind.Statements);
ss.Execute(scope);
```

----------- Python script -------

```
import clr 
clr.AddReference('System.Data')
from System import Data
from System.Data import DataTable

for row in mytable.Rows:
    row["TimeStamp"] = row["TimeStamp"] + 1
```

I tried many other options, but still the same error.

Comment: Try `row["TimeStamp"] = int(row["TimeStamp"]) + 1`

Comment: `42 + "nope, Python don't work like that"` - so convert the type as appropriate (and also, *search* for error messages)

Comment: (Whoops, not a "duplicate" of that which is int->str, but same idea just go str->int.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value referenced by accessing the key `"TimeStamp"` on the dictionary `row` is a string. Hence the error. Replace

```
row["TimeStamp"] = row["TimeStamp"] + 1
```

with

```
row["TimeStamp"] = int(row["TimeStamp"]) + 1
```

Comment: @user1291401 Please update the question with the new error as and complete Traceback. One line error messages are harder to debug without the corresponding code and error trace.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you're trying to use + operator with a str and an int. Check this:

```
>>> "012" + "345"
'012345'
>>> 1 + 1
2
>>> 1 + "012"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

So, to avoid raising the exception you either convert one of them to str or to int:

```
>>> 1 + int("012")
13
```

So, in your case I'd do:

```
row["TimeStamp"] = str( int(row["TimeStamp"]) + 1 )
```